# 404 page not found when requesting JSON from The Rundown API

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

Thank you for stopping by. I'm getting "404 page not found" message returned when I do a get request for The Rundown API. I have gone through the [docs](https://therundown.docs.stoplight.io/events/get-sports-sport-id-events), and I believe I'm using the appropriate URL.
I am specifically looking for events by sport, and I've used these two URLs:

https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events?include=scores *//supposed to return projected scores*

https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events *//supposed to return all events upcoming for this sport*

My API key is working, and I do get data from other URLs, i.e.

https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events/6-1-2019 *//returns data from the sports event on that day*

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "{my_api_key}"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I was wondering if I'm not getting any data because, possibly, schedules for many sports are messed up due to the pandemic... But I figured I would just get an empty object for something like that, and not a 404.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that their docs at the link above was outdated. Apparently, the above endpoints don't work anymore. [Here](https://rapidapi.com/therundown/api/therundown?endpoint=5ace94c1e4b00687d357c4e8) is the link to their new docs.
Now, if you want to get all future events for a particular sport, you can do something like this

```
url = "https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/dates"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "a305c330demsh7dded55db30fb5cp17605fjsnda27dcdd58f3"
}

res = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

dates = res.text
dates = json.loads(dates)
dates_list = dates["dates"]
for date in dates_list:
    event_url = "https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events/" + date
    event_res = requests.request("GET", event_url, headers=headers)
    print(event_res.text)
```